# Lexical error while using MINUS keyword in a sparql query

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology, triples

I ran the following queries in SPARQL in Jena framework against an ontology ( The wasBornIn predicate is present in the ontology )

```
select ?p where 
  {
   ?s ?p ?o FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s :wasBornIn ?o }
  }
```

and

```
select ?p where 
  { 
   { ?s ?p ?o } MINUS { ?s :wasBornIn ?o } 
  }
```

For the first query, I am getting the following errors :

```
null
Error: Lexical error at line 7, column 21.  Encountered: " " (32), after : "NOT"
```

and

```
null
Error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 5, column 16.
Was expecting:
"{" ...
```

For the second query, I am getting a similar error :

```
null
Error: Lexical error at line 5, column 38.  Encountered: " " (32), after : "MINUS"
```

Both the queries seems to be correct and I've no idea why I am getting those errors.

Comment: Where's the code that's actually generating the query.  I wouldn't be surprised if at least some of it is some string concatenation with some spaces missing.  E.g., `"?s ?p ?o" + "FILTER NOT EXISTS …"` producing `?s ?p ?oFILTER NOT …` with a variable `?oFILTER`.

Comment: I am not passing the query in the form of string. I am directly typing in the actual query. @JoshuaTaylor

Comment: Directly typing into what? You said that you were doing this with jena… we will need to see the code before we can't say anything else. As I mentioned in an answer both of the queries themselves are well formed.

Comment: I am typing the query in the output console of NetBeans. However I figured out the problem. The queries are valid as you said but turns out I understood the meaning of MINUS wrongly. I got it now. Thanks for the help @JoshuaTaylor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first and second queries (assuming that you've got the `:` prefix defined) are legal.  You can check with [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).  E.g., these are both legal:

```
prefix : <>

select ?p where 
  {
   ?s ?p ?o FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s :wasBornIn ?o }
  }
```

```
prefix : <>

select ?p where 
  { 
   { ?s ?p ?o } MINUS { ?s :wasBornIn ?o } 
  }
```

However, there's something you're not showing us;  you're mentioning that there's an error in line 7 (for the first) one, but the query you've shown doesn't have 7 lines.  Not only that, I'm not sure how you could encounter an EOF at line 5, and then still have a line 7 to get another error.  Perhaps there's something different about the code that's actually constructing the query.  Maybe you've got something like this:

```java
"?s ?p ?o" + 
"FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s :wasBornIn ?o }"
```

in which case you'd end up with

```
?s ?p ?oFILTER NOT EXISTS { … }
```

(i.e., with a variable named `?oFILTER`).  Without seeing your code, though, this would be hard to diagnose.  You could also be parsing the query incorrectly, somehow.